# news feed in instagram with flex has only 8 children?

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, instagram

i am looking at Instagram react elements using chrome devtools.
i have observed that one parent div(big parent) maintains height of all the articles i have scrolled through so far.inside this parent there is one more div(flex parent) which is a flex column with only 8 children(articles). the padding top and padding bottom are calculated for flex parent as, 
big parent height = flex parent's top-padding + flex parent height + flex parent' bottom-padding.

my question here is why limit flex column to have only 8 items. why can't we add every new article to fex column and get rid of padding-top padding-bottom logic for felx column. 
are we gaining some performace by maitaining only 8 items of newsfeed in flex parent ?[image]

Comment: what happens when you scroll? it keeps adding more content. So they have infinite scroll

Comment: my question is why have only 8 child items in flex. why maintain another parent over it called cGcGK. why can't we have entire child items inside flex itself?
i am curious why maintain limited no of items inside flex.
same thing they are doing in Twitter as well.

Comment: I don't have Instagram, but I know twitter has an infinite scroll. So you are asking the wrong question here. Since they have more than a million users each day they don't want to load 100 posts when you are not even gonna look at them.

say you have 10.000 users and all of them opens the twitter page. If everybody would have 100 posts loaded that would be 10.000 x 100 = 1.000.000 posts shown.

Comment: Say that none of the users want to see any post, but they want to change their profile. That is 1.000.000 posts shown for nothing.

 So instead of showing 1.000.000 post, they choose to show 8 posts instead.
that is 10.000 x 8 = 80.000 posts shown for nothing. If you want to see more posts you start scrolling and it will load more posts. 

So this is why they are showing 8 posts instead of all of them. They don't want the server to do unnecessary requests.

that is how you should think

Comment: that makes sense i got different perspective thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Instagram, but I know twitter has an infinite scroll. So you are asking the wrong question here. Since they have more than a million users each day they don't want to load 100 posts when you are not even gonna look at them. say you have 10.000 users and all of them opens the twitter page. If everybody would have 100 posts loaded that would be 10.000 x 100 = 1.000.000 posts shown

Say that none of the users want to see any post, but they want to change their profile. That is 1.000.000 posts shown for nothing. So instead of showing 1.000.000 post, they choose to show 8 posts instead. that is 10.000 x 8 = 80.000 posts shown for nothing. If you want to see more posts you start scrolling and it will load more posts. So this is why they are showing 8 posts instead of all of them. They don't want the server to do unnecessary requests. that is how you should think